# Some picture cannot display on image

Tags: wpf, image, bitmapimage

I have something unclear, I got 1 image which will be display the image based from the URL. There is some image that goes to exception. Below are my code:

```
If File.Exists(myequip) Then
      image1 = New BitmapImage()
      image1.BeginInit()
      image1.UriSource = New Uri(myequip, UriKind.Relative)
      image1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
      image1.EndInit()
      imgequip.Source = image1
      imgequip.Stretch = Stretch.Fill
End If
```

All pictures in JPG. The exception jumps at EndInit. When I open the image using Windows Photo Viewer, it have the pictures. Not corrupted. Any idea why this is happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your UriKind to absolute and please check your uristring (myequip)

```
  image1 = New BitmapImage()
  image1.BeginInit()
  image1.UriSource = New Uri(myequip, UriKind.Absolute)
  image1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
  image1.EndInit()
  imgequip.Source = image1
  imgequip.Stretch = Stretch.Fill
```

Comment: Even better, do not set the UriKind at all: `image1.UriSource = New Uri(myequip)`.

Comment: yeah clemens, i do not put urikind anymore. just straight to the point :)